# Using Function MaxRange with mixed characters (letters and numbers)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the maximum number value of a column, but each value in that column starts with letter characters (MT###). After the maximum is found, my variable 'LastSerial' is assigned to it, the column autofills with increasing values, a new maximum is found within the column, and rinse and repeat within this loop.

```
Private Sub ButtonOK_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SerialList As Range
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lv As Variant
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim strFind As Variant
    Dim todaysDate As String
    Dim LastSerial As Long 'latest serial number already in log
    todaysDate = ws.Range("L3")


'Takes what values were added to the Scrap List Box within the userform finds them in B column of Sheet1, and udpates their same-row Scrap Date and     Scrap Initials fields. Then finds next available
'serial number (casting) and adds an equal number of values present in the                         ListBox2 to the serial number list count.
With ws
    For j = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        'LastSerial is largest value found in F column
        LastSerial = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("F:F"))
        lv = Me.ListBox2.List(j)
        Set SerialList = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:=lv, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not SerialList Is Nothing Then
                If LastSerial = "0" Or IsNull(LastSerial) Then
                    MsgBox "Error: Serial Log has a missing entry or no previous serial numbers.)"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    ws.Cells(SerialList.Row, "E").Value = todaysDate
                    ws.Cells(SerialList.Row, "F").Value = "MT" & LastSerial + 1
                    ws.Cells(SerialList.Row, "G").Value = TextBox3
                    ws.Cells(SerialList.Row, "H").Value = TextBox4
                    ws.Cells(SerialList.Row, "I").Value = TBInitials
                End If
            End If
    Next j
    MsgBox "Serial Numbers successfully added."
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Results: the code cannot find the last serial because MT### isn't a number, but I don't know which function to use to split the MT from the number and evaluate only the number. I thought about using the LEFT or RIGHT function but I'm not sure how to implement that inside of the MAX function.

Comment: Consider creating a "helper" column (that could be far off the normal use area, or even on a separate sheet). Each cell in the helper column would then strip the leading characters to leave you with just the numbers `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)`. Then have your sub use the `Max` function on that helper column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function CustomMax(ByVal someRange As Range, Optional ByVal Prefix As String = "MT") As Long
    Debug.Assert someRange.Cells.CountLarge > 1
    Debug.Assert someRange.Areas.Count = 1

    Dim inputArray As Variant
    inputArray = someRange.Value

    Dim lengthOfPrefix As Long
    lengthOfPrefix = Len(Prefix)

    Dim serialStartsAt As Long
    serialStartsAt = lengthOfPrefix + 1

    ' Assumes inputArray is 2-dimensional
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)

        If Not IsError(inputArray(rowIndex, 1)) Then

            Dim Stringified As String
            Stringified = CStr(inputArray(rowIndex, 1))

            If StrComp(Prefix, Left$(Stringified, lengthOfPrefix), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                Dim serialParsed As String
                serialParsed = Mid$(Stringified, serialStartsAt)

                If IsNumeric(serialParsed) Then
                    Dim maxThusFar As Long
                    maxThusFar = Application.Max(maxThusFar, CLng(serialParsed)) ' Whole numbers only assumed
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rowIndex

    CustomMax = maxThusFar

End Function
```

I haven't seen your worksheet, but based on your code, you might just be able to swap this line in your code:

```
LastSerial = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("F:F"))
```

with:

```
LastSerial = CustomMax(Range("F:F"))
```

- Also, I think the `CustomMax` function will return a 0 (by default) if there are no MT### values. To change this behaviour, you could change its return type to something else (e.g. `Variant`).
- The function does a few checks (for errors, for prefix, for numeric serial, etc) -- which may or may not make sense depending on the contents of the range.
- You might want to detect the last row instead of passing the entire column to the function (as the function attempts to read the entire range into an array). Otherwise, performance may suffer or you may receive memory-related errors.
- Function needs a better name than `CustomMax`.

Comment: Wonderful answer chillin, thank you! In response to your third bullet, the Max MT### can appear in different rows of column F, so choosing the last row may not actually give the maximum value of column F. Maybe I could filter it to all rows in col F with values other that ""

Comment: Update: It works like a charm.

You are correct that it is kindof sluggish, I might adjust the size of the Range being entered into the "CustomMax" Function. The MT### Serial Numbers are based on actual parts being produced. Based on production, I don't see the MT### eclipsing MT50000 for the next 30 years.

Comment: Great, no problem. #1 If I recall correctly `Application.Max` (used above) is relatively slow (maybe it does a lot of checks against input) and it might be ~80 times faster to create a custom function in its place -- which returns the larger of two numbers. #2 When I said detecting the last row, I didn't mean that the largest `MT###` is in the last row. I meant if the last used row in column F is cell `F10000` (for example), then maybe pass `F1:F10000` instead of `F:F` to the function -- as the former will process ~1 million fewer cells (depending on Excel version), which helps performance.

Comment: If you find performance to be too sluggish, I can try to implement the two points in my comment (to improve performance). Up to you.

Comment: Ok gotcha. I changed it from F:F to  F7:F25000, which is a far larger range than I anticipate we will need. It runs fast as I need it. By the time we hit MT25000, either the orders of parts will have ceased, a new part will be ordered thus new serials, or a new software will be available.